# Flex 3 custom components positioning - popups

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, popup, flex3

I have created a custom TitleWindow whcih i use as a popup. The contents of the popup are created dynamically depending on a selection a user makes from a datagrid.

My problem is, my datagrid is in another custom component whcih is toward the bottom of my page so when a user clicks one of the items the popup is displayed however with half of it out of sight at the bottom of the page.

Is there a way to position a popup so that it displays at the top of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know at least two things you can use to position a popup, though there might be more.

When you place a popup you can choose in which parent component to place the popup:

```
PopUpManager.createPopUp(this.parent, TitleWindowComponent);
```

In the component itself:

```
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a help tooltip type popup (with help text) to appear next to the icon that opened it. In the end I used move(x,y) to move the window where I wanted it. To get the coordinates to place it, use globalToLocal:

```
var globalX:Number = localToGlobal(new Point(myIcon.x, myIcon.y)).x;
var globalY:Number = localToGlobal(new Point(myIcon.x, myIcon.y)).y;

toolTip.move(globalX + myIcon.width, globalY);
```

That puts the window just to the right of the icon, myIcon.